# How to remove HtmlScriptElement in C#

Tags: c#, removechild

How can I programatically remove an appended html element?

Here's my code (I want to remove scriptEl like it never existed) and any InvokeScript to the web browser results in error or no action all:

```
HtmlElement head = instance.webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = instance.webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement; 
element.text = scriptText;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

I've been struggling with this with no success. Every invocation of the script is valid from the command InvokeScript. There should exist a function like RemoveChild. How can I accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<HtmlElement> toRemove = new List<HtmlElement>();
foreach (HtmlElement element in Form.Children)
{
    if (element.Id != string.Empty)
    {
        toRemove.Add(element);
    }
}
foreach (HtmlElement element in toRemove)
{
    Form.RemoveChild(element);
}
```

Comment: That is for Silverlight. I'm using a system windows forms with a browser embedded and HtmlElement (from Microsoft.mshtml assembly) does not include any RemoveChild at all.

Comment: I'm realizing that is impossible. The first function always prevail. Meanwhile the workaround I did was making generic javascript functions a pass a json object as argument.